# Visual Studio 2010 C# using defines from wrong project to highlight code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2010 (Pro) solution with two projects in it that include the same file. Most of the file is enclosed by:

```
#if MY_DEFINE
a bunch of code here..
#endif
```

One of the projects defines MY_DEFINE and the other doesn't.

Visual Studio seems to choose a value of MY_DEFINE randomly for Intellisense. Sometimes, the code inside that #if block shows up with proper syntax highlighting and sometimes it doesn't. It doesn't seem to matter which project I've marked as the startup project in Solution Explorer.

This is a real problem because I can't even set breakpoints inside the #if, **even if I'm running the project that has MY_DEFINE in the debugger**.

Does anyone know how Visual Studio chooses which project's defines to use for Intellisense (and for letting you set breakpoints)?

Comment: What do you mean, two projects including the same file?  Are there two copies of the file, or are you using a link to a file?

Comment: Yes, there are two projects linking to the same .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

It should use the defines from the project that is being started. Therefore, if you have more than one "runnable" (non-library) projects, I believe it will use the defines from the running one. Is this not what you are experiencing?

Comment: Right, I'm not seeing it using the defines from the project being started. It seems almost random which defines it chooses to use.